# Algorithm to cluster chart type

Tags: r, algorithms

So, I have more than 20,000 entities. Each entities has their own data point (time series). Let say entities A1 to A20000. A1 has data point from year 1 to year 60. A2 has data point from year 5 to 60, and so on. We can make some plot year vs value each year for each entities.

My task now is to make a cluster of the entity based on the shape the chart they make. For example, A1 data point chart (assume barplot) will make quadratic-like shape, A2 data point chart will make exponential -like shape, and so on. There would be some entity with random chart shape like scattered.

Is there any algorithm to create this type of clustering? I tried to create just 1 shape detection algorithm, monotonic increase shape, and I think it works good but I need an automatic shape detection algorithm. My method also still not robust enough to detect some small fluctuation. For example in the monotonic increase shape (the data in the newer year is greater than its previous year), if some data in a year dropped a quite big, it failed to detect it is monotonic increase type although generally speaking, it is monotonic increase.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe google polynomial interpolation?

Comment: I would compute correlation coefficients between time series and make the distance between two time series 1 - correlation^2. Then use this matrix of distances with your preferred clustering algorithm - or try several and see if you like one better than the other.

Comment: Calculating correlation is a good idea, but the size of the data point for every entity can be different. For example, for entity A, I have data for 25 years but entity B only have the data for 15 years.

Answer (score 1):

Your request made me wonder if the functional data analysis framework might be helpful. In R it is implemented in the tools within several packages, all with the letters "fda" in their titles. A tutorial isn't made available by the authors but a book is: "Functional Data Analysis with R and Matlab (2010)" and there is a somewhat aging presentation given at a useR conference: http://user2007.org/program/presentations/ramsay.pdf as well as a slightly more recent shout course syllabus: http://faculty.bscb.cornell.edu/~hooker/ShortCourseHandout.pdf.

Comment: I have tried to use FDA library in R. It is good and I have a general idea how to use it. My idea is to generate FDA curve for several representative shape, for example sine line curve, exponential like curve, etc. After that, I will calculate correlation of the data sample that I want to check with the FDA curve. If the correlation is good, it means that the data sample is in that curve shape. How do you think about that? I also have another question if you have any experience using FDA library in R.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I think that you should run an automated Empirical Orthogonal Functions (EOF) Analysis, with its corresponding principal components, to cluster your entities based on the "chart" type.

In a sense, EOF Analysis is conceptually similar to Fourier Analysis (FA), with the only difference that in FA you always use a set of known functions (Sine and Cosine) as the eigenfunctions, while in EOF Analysis, this tools helps us determine what the eigenfunctions should be, and their relative importance.

I hope this helps you with this problem.

Kind regards, GEN

Comment: This is interesting. But do you think it would work? My data is really simple. Nothing complex at all.

Comment: Also, my data is only 1 dimension for each entity. Imagine the data is a simple table Year~Score for 1 entity and I have 20,000 entities with this kind of table.

Comment: I do not argue the fact that each entity has its own data set, and those datesets are simple, but the point is that you need to cluster your different entities according to "chart" type, and the "chart" type actually expressed the functional relationship that exists between your independent variables and your dependent variable(s) for any given entity.

As the "chart" type is actually the functional relationship, you need a tool that should be able to determine or identify the functional relationship that each entity has associated.

Kind regards, GEN

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. i want to ask about the dependent variable. From what I understand, each entity is separate thing. I have read some example about FDA in : http://www.psych.mcgill.ca/misc/fda/examples.html
I can say that my data is similar to wather data, but the weather measured in different location. In the example, the place is same which is in Canada. The data is taken from different station. My data on the other hand would be, let's say, different city or maybe even different country. So, the data has no relationship from one entity to other entity. Totally individual data

Comment: EOF Analysis is strongly used with weather models, but it is not the only area of application.

For instance, Fourier Analysis (FA) is strongly used in sound analysis and by sound synthesizers, but sound is not the only area of application for FA.

For instance, FA is also strongly used in Quantum Field Theories.

Just to give an example, the most common demonstration for the Uncertainty Principle, as was stated by Heisenberg and Bohr, is a case of FA applied to a quantum theory.

Back to EOF Analysis, it could be applied to the type of problem you are facing.

Kind regards, GEN

Comment: I see, so what I understand is like this: merge all 20,200 enity into single matrix and then fill the missing data, because the length of the data can be vary but I can get the max and min (let say 1901-2017, for data that only has 1990-2017, the rest are set to 0). After I have such huge matrix, I run the EOF analysis to get the principal component. Those prinicipal component will determine the cluster that can be extracted from the matrix. After that I reversed the cluster to get which entities are in those principal component. Is that right? I only have basic experience with PCA so far.

Comment: Also, another condition is, because the length of the data are different, do you thing EOF will work? I want to be able to analyse even though the pattern are not on the same time. Let say Entity A has sinus type chart between year 1990-2017 and Entity B also has sinus type chart between 1970-1990. Do you think EOF can recognize this type of similarity? I expect my "chart type" recognition is time independent. It doesn't matter where the X axis the pattern start, I just want to identify the pattern.

Comment: It will work, no matter if the extent of time is different for different sets of data.